# blazor wasm project errors only on visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, blazor, blazor-webassembly

i have a blazor wasm app that runs whiteout problems, in visual studio i have no errors messages , But when i open it with visual studio code i have this error messages :

The type or namespace name 'MainLayout' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The type or namespace name 'NavMenu' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Unable to open 'App.razor__virtual.cs': Unable to read file 'd:\VisualCodeProjects\GestionBLZ\GestionBLZ\Client\App.razor__virtual.cs' (Error: Unable to resolve non-existing file 'd:\VisualCodeProjects\GestionBLZ\GestionBLZ\Client\App.razor__virtual.cs').
I tried it in visual studio and i had no errors

[image]

Comment: What does it say when you try to build it?